# MongoDB dynamic query with javascript, working static, not with variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I've been writing an app in express, using a standard mongodb driver, version 3.2.6. I need to make a query to my database, and I'd like to make it for 5 years and count entries for each year. When I write the code statically it works without problem, if I so much put the same exact value into a variable and insert it into the query, it refuses to work.

I apologize if this is something obvious I missed, but I fail to find a solution. Thanks for everyone attempting to help :)

This code works. The output is bellow

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    result = {
        title : "Somethings through time",
        data : []
    }
    for(let i = 4;i<9;i++) {
        const query = `/2014/`;
        db.getDB().collection("somethings").find({"date_of_something": /2014/}).count().then(numOf => {
            console.log(query +"\n"+numOf);
        });
    }
    res.json({
        success: false
    });
});
```

Output:

```
[0] /2014/
[0] 24263
[0] /2014/
[0] 24263
[0] /2014/
[0] 24263
[0] /2014/
[0] 24263
[0] /2014/
[0] 24263
```

This code does not work.

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    result = {
        title : "Somethings through time",
        data : []
    }
    for(let i = 4;i<9;i++) {
        const query = `/2014/`;
        db.getDB().collection("somethings").find({"date_of_something": query}).count().then(numOf => {
            console.log(query +"\n"+numOf);
        });
    }
    res.json({
        success: false
    });
});
```

Output:

```
[0] /2014/
[0] 0
[0] /2014/
[0] 0
[0] /2014/
[0] 0
[0] /2014/
[0] 0
[0] /2014/
[0] 0
```

Comment: Also, I'm using the backticks (`) because I eventually want the query to look like `$201{i}`, to loop through years. The query does not work with " or ' either :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regex

```
/2014/
```

But this one with back ticks is just a normal string

```
`/2014/`
```

To create a new regex from a string you can do it like this

```
const query = new RegExp(`201${i}`)
```

In MongoDB to match using a regex you should use [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator

```
{"date_of_something": {$regex: query}}
```

Also worth noting you're returning the result `res.json` without waiting for the queries to finish, you should `await` for the queries, and the request handler should be `async`

```
router.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
    ...
    const numOf = await db.getDB().collection("somethings")
                   .find({"date_of_something": {$regex: query}}).count();
    console.log(query +"\n"+numOf);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know what I've been doing wrong. But this still does not work for me. I still get 0 results if I use what you've written.

Comment: `date_of_something` is a date type field? how is the data look like

Comment: This is what the data looks like, "03.01.2014". it is a date in our format, written as a string, not an actual date type. Unless mongo automatically detected it, from importing a json file.

Comment: Where should I put the async? The await part is underlined red if I just use that.
The regex is not working if I keep it how it was though. If I type out the regex in the $regex: field it works, as a variable, not so much.

Comment: The async and await work now. The regex still getting no hits as a variable. Working flawlessly typed out.

Comment: oh sorry, updated, creating a regex from a string doesn't need to add the extra / , like this RegExp(`201${i}`)

Comment: Yes, this solves it! Thank you sir, you've enabled me to sleep tonight :)